# Fourier transform of interesting function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Let the Fourier transform of a function and its inverse be given as:

$\mathcal{F}[f](\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-i\lambda t} dt$

$f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{F}[f](\lambda)e^{i\lambda t} d\lambda$

For $a>0$, let $\psi_a:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by:

$\psi_a(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{2a}{a^2+t^2}$

I want to show that the fourier transform of $\psi_a$ is $\mathcal{F}[\psi_a](\lambda) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-a|\lambda|}$. I know that the fourier transform of $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ is $\mathcal{F}[\frac{1}{1+t^2}](\lambda) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-|\lambda|}$. I figured I could use this fact to somehow find the transform of $\psi_a$ using properties regarding the fourier transform of a translation or a rescaling, but it seems to me that $\psi_a$ is neither a rescaling or a translation of $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
\psi_a(t)&=\frac{a}{a^2+t^2} \\
\phi(t)&=\frac{1}{1+t^2}
\end{align}
then
\begin{equation}
\psi_a(t)=\frac{1}{a}\phi(t/a).
\end{equation}
Assume knowledge of the Fourier transform of a function $f(t)$, then a the function $g(t)=C f(t/a)$ has Fourier transform
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}[g](\lambda)=C\int_{\mathbb{R}}dt e^{-i\lambda t} f(t/a)=C a\int_{\mathbb{R}}dt' e^{-i a \lambda t'} f(t')=C a \, \mathcal{F}[f](a\lambda),
\end{equation}
Applying this relation to our case
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}[\psi_a](\lambda)=\mathcal{F}[\phi](a\lambda)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you for the answer, makes sense!